# Add commits to a pull request as a repo's owner

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have received several pull-requests on one of my repos. They are good but there are some small fixes (typos, for example) which I would like to fix myself so that I can merge the PR faster.

Now, how can I add my commits to that particular PR? The PR author forked my repo, worked on his, then submitted the PR.

And, as a side question, how does GitHub for Mac handle checking out a PR? Where will be commit go if a commit some changes, then push them while on the PR checkout?

Comment: This is basically the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563008/pushing-a-commit-to-branch-of-another-user-who-has-opened-a-pull-request/58061658#58061658

Comment: @SybillePeters I asked the question 2 years before the one you linked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a branch (a merge test branch) starting with `master`.

Either merge each commit in turn and use `git commit --amend`, or go through them in turn with `git rebase -i`, choosing the `e` option. If you want to reset the author, add `--reset-author`.

In the comments the author says he wants to add a separate commit. In this case, use `git rebase -i` again (using the SHA-1 of master, i.e. before the merges), and add the additional commit before `git rebase --continue`.

When you've done, merge your test branch back to master.

---

Another way without `git rebase`.

- Checkout each PR (I'll take it as fact you can do this with `git checkout pr/X`).
- Create and check out a local branch based on this (`git checkout -b to-merge-PR-X`)
- Add your commit (edit + `git add` + `git commit`)
- Push this (if you like - optional) to github: (`git push -u origin to-merge-PR-X` assuming github is `origin`).
- (perhaps do other things here, like fix up the rest)
- Merge the branch into master `git checkout master` + `git merge to-merge-PR-X`
- Fix up any merge conflicts
- Repeat for all branches to merge
- Push resultant master to github (`git push`)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to add _to_ the contributor's commits, I want to add a **separate** commit, on top of the contributor's, that does the fixes I was talking about.

Comment: OK, but what do I check out in order to rebase. And also, won't the date of the contributor's commits be changed when rebasing? Then, where do I push? Can you give this scenario a bit more detailed, please? Also, do you have any idea regarding my side question?

Comment: I've amended the answer, but you check out what you want to rebase onto. No, the date of the contributors commit is within the commit, so if you add separate commits only they will have a new date; `rebase` does not change commit dates. You merge back to master then push it where you want (github's `master` I presume). Your side question should be a separate question on SE. I use Github and I use the Mac (and Linux) but I don't use 'GitHub for Mac' - indeed I don't even know what it is. CLI all the way.

Comment: I still don't get it, maybe I haven't made myself clear enough. Someone open a pull request on myrepo:dev from hisrepo:dev. I see that on GitHub a pull request is references as myrepo:pr/X, where X is a number. I want to checkout that pull request ref, add a commit to it, then put push my change to that I can merge the pull request. I am not sure what to checkout (myrepo:pr/X or hisrepo:dev), and if I push the changes, what will be updated (the pull request, his branch, or both). I don't think I need to rebase anything for this.

Comment: You cannot (I presume) commit to his repo. `git rebase` is for more than just rebasing. It's my main tool for *re-ordering* and for *editing* commits (specifically `git rebase -i`); forget it's called `rebase` and life will be easier. I'll edit the above to put in another way to achieve what you want without rebase.

Comment: Thank you for your update. The second version is clear to me. You say it is equivalent to the first one?

Comment: Pretty much. The first route is more traditional - you merge in patch by patch and after each patch fix it up. In the second route you fix up each patch in separate branches. The first route is probably easier for small non-overlapping patch sets. The second route is probably easier for large complex overlapping patches which might conflict.