# Pushing a commit to branch of another user who has opened a pull request

Tags: git, github, push, commit, git-branch

I have a repository on github. My repository is forked by another user. Now he has raised a pull request. I would like to push one commit from my end to his feature branch(for which he has raised a PR). Is this possible.

Here is what I did

```
git pull remote-ref-other-user feature-branch
```

After doing this I am able to pull his commits. but when I do some change, add another commit and try to push it this way.

```
git push remote-ref-other-user feature-branch
```

I get this error

```
error: src refspec feature-branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/other-user/repo'
```

> Is it possible to push a commit from my side to his branch. If yes then how can it be done.

Comment: You can always issue a counter PR to the forked repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you add his repository, say "mysamplerepository", as a remote:

`git remote add johnrepo https://github.com/john/mysamplerepository`

And you have your branch called `tweaks`.

If you want to push your changes to a branch called `master` in his repository, you would do:

`git push <remote-name> <source-ref>:<target-ref>`

or in this example:

`git push johnrepo refs/heads/tweaks:refs/heads/master`

Remember that you also need to have write permission (push access) to push to his repository. You can read more about this on [Github's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/).

Comment: Thanks @kopranb it worked. `git push <remote-name> <source-ref>:<target-ref>` This command worked for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

If this is possible, will depend on write permissions:

- as repository owner, you should have write permission to add commits to PR of another user (unless this was explicitly turned off in the PR of the user)
- if you are not repository owner, you will not be able to add additional commits to PR of another user

After adding the remote for the GitHub user, e.g.

```
git remote add <name of remote> git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
```

I use

```
git checkout -b <name of branch> <name of remote>/<name of branch>
```

to create a local branch tracking the remote. After I made changes and committed, I can do:

```
git push <name of remote> <name of branch>
```